# Getting an empty space in up sell items

Tags: php, errors

I have the current version of wp, and I'm using the tailor theme, and I have my up sell section set up so items show up. However, if an item is out of stock, it creates a random empty space instead of just showing the other up sell items. For example, if the second item is sold out, it will show item 1, large space, item 3. Is there a way to have it dynamically "fix" the up sell list? So in the example it would just be item 1, item 3.

Comment: If you provide the code snippet that is generating the snippets you would likely get some help.  Also, can you provide a URL?  I am curious, maybe it is adding a class we could use to hide the sold item one.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: https://friedmans.com/product/simulated-diamond-stud-earrings-1-12ctw/

Comment: It looks like that area is using Owl Carousel, I don't know anything about it but have you looked to see if there is any setting to hide out of stock products?  I could write a script that detect if it's empty and then hide the html block but that is hacky and there is a better way

Comment: It is using that and there is a setting to not show out of stock items for the whole site that is turned on. That's also the line of thought I was heading down, but I was wondering if there was maybe a setting I overlooked to get it to not return the empty space. I'll more into the owl carousel to see if there is a setting in there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was that the query calling the items was checking to see if the main item (i.e. the product the user clicked on) was in stock, not the actual up sell items. Can add code snippets later if needed